# Anyobject? does not have a member named "removeAtIndex"

Tags: swift

I'm trying to remove a cell from my tableViewCell. I have a plist made up of string values. However AnyObject doesn't seem to contain removeAtIndex. The following is the relevant code.

```
var citiesArray: AnyObject? = nil;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //loading an array from a file
    var documentList=NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("EuropeanCapitals", ofType:"plist")
    citiesArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile:documentList);

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:        UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        if let tv=tableView
        {
            citiesArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row) /* Throws Error */
            tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }
```

I tried declaring citiesArray as NSArray? and I get  NSArray? does not have a member named 'removeAtIndex'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`removeAtIndex()` is not a method on NSArray or AnyObject. You can try to convert your NSArray to a Swift Array and then call that method.

```
if var citiesArr = citiesArray as? Array<AnyObject>{
    citiesArr.removeAtIndex(0)
}
```

`removeObjectAtIndex()` is also available on NSMutableArray if you want to use that instead.

Comment: Connor i tried and i got 'Array<AnyObject> is not a subtype of 'NSArray'

Comment: You cannot change NSArray. Only MutableArray has the property to add or remove objects.

Comment: I tried and I got NSMutableArray does not have a member named 'removeAtIndex' , how can that be?

Comment: It doesn't have that method. It's a method on Swift's Array

Comment: Try removeObjectAtIndex instead

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Comment: NSMutableArray? does not have a member named removeObjectAtIndex

Comment: add a ! citiesArray!.removeObjectAtIndex()

Comment: "removeAtIndex() is not a method on NSArray or AnyObject." You can try to call *any* `@objc` method on `AnyObject`.