# SWIFT - 'AnyObject' does not have a member name 'fooBar'

Tags: core-data, swift

I am trying to fetch some data from Core Data and have run into a slight problem. I can fetch the data with no problem. The moment I try to grab a specific piece of data (i.e. `data.fooBar`), it throws up an error:

> "'AnyObject' does not have a member name 'fooBar'

If I `println(data)` it will show that `fooBar` does exist with data stored in it.

I am not really sure why it is doing this. I have tried to search for an answer and tried a bunch of different things but none have seemed to work. Any help would be great. Thanks. :)

```
    var results : Array<AnyObject> = []


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    //get the data for that storedItem
    var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let req = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "storedItems")

    let name:String = results[indexPath.row].name
    req.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
    req.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var tapResults = context.executeFetchRequest(req, error: nil)!

    for item in tapResults {
        println(item) //works, shows all data correctly(including subText)
        println(item.name) //works, the only one that does for some reason???
        println(item.subText) //Error 'AnyObject' does not have a member name 'subText'
    }
```

Here is the result for: `println(item)`

```
 println(item) <NSManagedObject: 0x7f04be60> (entity: storedItems; id: 0x7f041de0 <x-coredata://DD4F8E68-2234-46B5-B1D8-AE2F75245C63/storedItems/p1> ; data: {
alarmSound = default;
isDefault = 0;
name = "test";
sliderHours = 0;
sliderMinutes = 0;
sliderSeconds = 0;
subText = "00:00:00";
```

---

**UPDATE**: Based on discussion over vacawama answer (Thank you Aaron). For correct solution please see the answer I accepted.

my itemObj class

```
  @objc(itemObj)
  class itemObj: NSManagedObject {

        @NSManaged var name:String!
        @NSManaged var sliderHours:NSNumber
        @NSManaged var sliderMinutes:NSNumber
        @NSManaged var sliderSeconds:NSNumber
        @NSManaged var subText:String!
        @NSManaged var alarmSound:String!
        @NSManaged var isDefault:NSNumber
    }
```

my AddItem VC:

```
    var tResults = (context.executeFetchRequest(req, error: nil))

    for item in tResults as [itemObj!] {

        println(item.name)
        println(item.subText)

    }
```

Comment: swift is type safe and there are 100s of questions dealing with issues exactly like this.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Thanks for the downvote, As you can see in my question, I have been searching for a while(still am). Can you please provide a link that may help me out.

Comment: many of the links in the related section match. as you asked for a link: try this: (I checked it and it does explain it) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770515/swift-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-removeatindex?rq=1 OR this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223549/swift-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-make?rq=1

Comment: what does it look like when you do `println(item)` ?  What does `context.executeFetchResult` return?  An array of dictionaries?

Comment: @vacawama I have added the results for println(item)

Comment: Using `valueForKey:` is not a good idea. You should cast `tapResults` so the compiler knows what the array contains.

Comment: @AaronBrager why is it better to cast tapResults? What would I cast it as?

Comment: @pantless_coder In case you ever change the type of object in your data model, or make a typo. Casting `tapResults` to `[YourManagedObjectSubclass]` will catch these errors; your current approach won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`executeFetchRequest` returns an optional array of `AnyObject`. You shouldn't force-unwrap it (this can cause a crash). So optionally unwrap it and do an optional cast (`as?`) to make sure the type is correct:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let req = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "storedItems")

    let name:String = results[indexPath.row].name
    req.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
    req.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let tapResults = context.executeFetchRequest(req, error: nil)

    if let presentResults = tapResults {
        if let castedResults = presentResults as? [MyManagedObjectSubclass] {
            for item in castedResults {
                println(item)
                println(item.name)
                println(item.subText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also changed all of your `var`s to `let`s since they don't need to be mutable.

Just replace `MyManagedObjectSubclass` with whatever your `NSManagedObject` subclass is.

Comment: I see, ill have a good look at what is going on here... thank you.